# How can I concat to one string several values that are returned from a select query

Tags: sql, string, oracle, select, concatenation

Newby question:

I have a select query that returns one column but several rows. This query looks like 'SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1'. 
The table looks like this:

```
COL1
-----
Val1
Val2
Val3
```

So the values that are returned are ‘Val1’, ‘Val2’ and ‘Val3’.

I want to create a query that creates a string that looks like

```
AA.Val1 BB_Val1, AA.Val2 BB_Val2, AA.Val3 BB_Val3
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select listagg('AA.' || col1 || ' BB_' || col1, ', ') within group (order by col1)
from t;
```

Comment: Missing space in front of `' BB_'`, but yes - that looks like the simplest option.